# Durable solution to get the user device type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm developping a C# MVC Application that requires to know what kind of device the user is using (desktop/phone/tablet).

I need this information to display the menu in different sizes/shapes.

I tried to use @Media Queries with different sizes. The problem is that sometime the resolution of the tablet is as large as a desktop screen, and i don't want the same design on both.

I searched on StackOverflow and found out about "User agent" but this solution isn't realiable apparently because this is always moving which is not a good thing.

Is there a durable solution without Media Queries/User Agent to know what device is the user using ?

Is_tablet,Is_Phone,Is_Mobile would be a dream but any compatible solution would give me satisfaction.

Comment: I feel media query breakpoints really are the way to go with this. Maybe checking out how bootstrap and foundation handle responsiveness across devices will help you with your design. My two cents.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no 100% working method, even through UserAgent works very well for the majority of devices. Developers usually offer a manual switch for the remaining devices (like a button "mobile version" and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Request.Browser will give you a an [HttpCapabilitiesBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase(v=vs.110).aspx) object which may have what you're looking for. I found the IsMobileDevice handy for choosing which content to display to mobile users.